# Проверка строки на наличие определенных символов и их замена

Tags: javascript

Задача состоит в том,чтобы при получение строки `str` проверить её на наличие римских цифр,и,если они находятся,заменить на арабские.
Строка имеет строгий порядок и выглядит так: `I+I`.
Всего должно быть 10 римских.

При выполнении моего кода появляется ошибка `Uncaught ReferenceError: I is not defined`

```
function rplc(str){
    var myString = str;
    if(myString.includes('I')){
    myString=myString.replace('I','1');
    console.log(myString);
  }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибку даёт не в самой функции, а в том месте, где вы передаёте аргумент. И уверен, что на вход вы даёте не строку `'I+I'`, а прям так и пишите `I+I`. В итоге и пишется эта ошибка, потому что переменной с таким именем в коде нет

---

Но код у вас всё равно неверный. `replace` заменит только одно вхождение символа, а не все. Надо использовать минимум `replaceAll`. Но даже с ним при большой строке код будет неверным. Потому что римские числа могут быть разные и например `I` встречаться в разных числах

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку,буду искать другой способ